# Non-fundamental interactions that are yet to be explained

Tags: optics, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, diffraction

I was trying to understand some of the non-fundamental interactions in physics. I stress **non-fundamental**, because I am a student of particle physics and in the first semester of the master's we have been taught many of the phenomena that occurs due to matter-matter interactions and matter-light interactions, however I found myself not completely understood some of them near my graduation. In high energy physics we focus on fundamental interactions, but when I questioned "**how does rayleigh scattering feynman diagram look like**", or "**how can the single slit experiment be modeled by using only fundamental interactions**" I find myself stuck. Of course I have some insight into them I don't know that I understood them completely. For example I saw an article on "*Quantum theory of Rayleigh scattering*" which was published in 2021, and asked to myself, "wait, aren't those things well understood already?". So, my first guess was that maybe these interactions work at a more macroscopic level. However, I don't want to come to a conclusion all by myself with half-accurate guesses. If you can explain and give examples to several phenomena that are in scope of physics but not quite well described, I would be very grateful.

Comment: ‘how can the single slit experiment be modeled by using only fundamental interactions" … how can the exhaust engine be modeled from QED?

Comment: Well, single slit experiment was just an example. If you like, think it as the diffraction of X-rays from a crystal structure of some molecule, like x-ray crystallography. It is a bit smaller scale now.

Answer (score 1):

In physics, the abstractions are not fundamental, the phenomena are. Rayleigh scattering is well modeled by a semi-classical theory. But the more abstract the theory, the more disconnected it is from the phenomena.

Note that the word "electricity" originally meant "triboelectricity". Thus, triboelectricity is fundamental in that its study led us to abstractions that capture many phenomena accurately. Unfortunately, the abstractions have left triboelectricity far behind, so it remains poorly understood.

History suggests that if a "theory of everything" is ever formulated, it will be so remote from reality that it will be untestable. Perhaps this has already happened. Meanwhile, real, fundamental, physical phenomena like triboelectricity beg for study.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got a bit disappointed first, but after thinking on it for a while I understood what you meant. :) I wanted to model many things starting from the first principles, and to try to connect what I learned to the other stuff that I thought I knew. I still have doubts how a prescription can be valid if those are not explained at the fundamental level, but I will try not to forget how the things are defined and at which scale they are explained, and worry about them later if things start to cause anomalies in our current understanding.